# Angular2 - interrupt lite server workflow to download additional npm packages?

Tags: node.js, angular, lite-server

I have Angular2 app running with 5 minute setup project. Once the lite-server starts running  (after npm start) the console's cursor is not responsive to commands anymore. Is there a way to interrupt the lite server to download additional packages within the same process? Or is the only way to terminate the current process (Ctrl+C) and then restart lite server again after packages were loaded?

Comment: Have you considered just opening another terminal?

Comment: thank you, I have no issues working with 2 terminals if that's how it's meant to be